# Two collections in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections `Basic_aminities` and `Building`. I want the building name via `basic_aminities` collections.

Basic_aminities:

```javascript
{ "_id" : "BA1", 
"Property_id" : "B1", 
"hospital " : "5 km", 
"bahn_station" : "6 km ",
"restaurant" : "4 km",
"University" : "20 km",
"police_station" : "8 km",
"Airport" : "40 km",
"city_center" : " 5 km" }
```

Building collection:

```javascript
{ "_id" : "B1", 
"Sale_type" : "Rental", 
"Building_name" : "swamy", }
```

Here is my query which I tried to connect two collections in mongoDB. I need the `building_name` via the collection `basic_aminities`:

```javascript
db.Basic_aminities.find({ Property_id : {$exists: true}, 
                          Property_id.B1 : Building_name })
```

Can anyone please tell me how to write query?

Comment: Hello, as I presume you are a new user, please read the guidelines before asking for assistance. First of all, you should properly edit your code and you should not be expecting people to be offering a free answer without you previously trying to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Hello, I am new to Mongo DB. here is my query which i tried to connect two collections in mongoDB. I need the building_name via the collection basic_aminities db.Basic_aminities.find({
    Property_id : {$exists: true},
    Property_id.B1 : Building_name
                   
}) can anyone please tell me how to do that.